# Extract outlook email body and recipient email address using python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I am trying to extract outlook email body, recipient address, subject and received date.

I was able to extract subject and received date but unable to extract body and recipient address:

Below is my code for subject and received date:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')

namespace = outlook.Session

recipient = namespace.CreateRecipient("abc@xyz.com")

inbox = outlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 6)

messages = inbox.Items

email_subject = []

email_date = []

email_date_time = []


for x in messages:
    sub = x.Subject
    received_date = x.senton.date()
    received_date_time = str(x.ReceivedTime)
    email_subject.append(sub)
    email_date.append(received_date)
    email_date_time.append(received_date_time)
```

For body i am trying:

```
for x in messages:
    body = x.Body
    print(body)
```

but this is not working and i am getting the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-85-d79967933b99>", line 2, in <module>
    sub = x.Body

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)

com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)
```

Comment: What does it mean "this is not working"?  Please include full stack trace of the error, or if there is not an error, you need to describe how the actual output may differ from what you expect.

Comment: I am getting this error : Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-82-d79967933b99>", line 2, in <module>
    sub = x.Body

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)

com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `received_date = x.SentOn`? I'm pretty sure `senton.date()` is not valid in the Outlook object model. Python is case sensitive for starters, and there is no `date` property or method of the `SentOn` property.

Comment: Also, the traceback you provide in comment does **not** align with any portion of the code you provided. Please revise your question so that it is coherent.

Comment: `received_date = x.senton.date()`....this is working perfectly fine for me. I have updated the question too.

Comment: gotcha. just tested. `senton` is part of pywintypes and mirrors `SentOn`. it looks like many or maybe all of the object members are replicated, e.g., `m.body` and `m.Body`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've just run similar code on my computer, in an inbox with 3,000+ items of mixed type (skype message notifications, calendar invites/notifications, emails, etc.) and I cannot replicate this error, even for items where `not m.Body` -- I thought that was a possible culprit, maybe  a certain type of item doesn't have a body would throw an error -- but that appears to not be the case:

```
>>> for m in messages:
...     if not m.body:
...         print(m.Subject)
...         print(m.Body)
...
Accepted: Tables discussion

Message Recall Failure: tables/ new data status

Message Recall Failure: A few issues with the data
```

You should probably add a `print(m.Class)` because I still think that maybe certain types of items do not have a `Body` property.

[This thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2016-April/013701.html) suggests that there may be a user/security setting that prevents programmatic access to Outlook, so you might want to double-check on that (though I think if not allowed, none of your code would work -- still, worth looking in to!).

> I have figured out the source of this error. We are running into issues with the comObjectModelGaurd. Our group policy recently changed to disallow programatic access to protected mailItem objects.
>
> Modifying Outlook Users Trust settings or the registry will fix the problem.

Since I can't replicate the error, perhaps I can still help you debug and identify the source of the problem, from which we can probably come up with a good solution.

Use a function to get the item's body, and use `try/except` to identify which items are causing error.

```
def getBody(m):
     s = ""
     try:
         s = m.Body
     except COMError:
         s = '\t'.join(('Error!', m.Class, m.senton.date(), m.Subject))
     return s


for m in messages:
    print(getBody(m))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried the following code as per your suggestion :

`def getBody(m):
     s = ""
     try:
         s = m.Body
     except COMError:
         s = '\t'.join(('Error!', m.Class, m.senton.date(), m.Subject))
     return s


for m in messages:
    print(getBody(m))` 
and then i got this error  ---->>`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-84-473cc9cfd962>", line 11, in <module>
    print(getBody(m))

  File "<ipython-input-84-473cc9cfd962>", line 5, in getBody
    except COMError:

NameError: name 'COMError' is not defined`

Comment: you could change that to Error instead of COMError

Comment: after trying this code `def getBody(m):
     s = ""
     try:
         s = m.Body
     except Error:
         s = '\t'.join(('Error!', m.Class, m.senton.date(), m.Subject))
     return s
 
for m in messages:
    print(getBody(m))` i am still getting an error ---->> `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-98-2c19cb4ddfd4>", line 11, in <module>
    print(getBody(m))

  File "<ipython-input-98-2c19cb4ddfd4>", line 5, in getBody
    except Error:

NameError: name 'Error' is not defined`

Comment: @biker007 OK, switch it back to `Exception` rather than `Error`. Do you understand what a NameError is? You should look in to that and also look in to basic error handling in python :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that I found a solution that worked. For me it was an issue with permissions, but I made the registry edits in https://www.slipstick.com/developer/change-programmatic-access-options/ and it worked a treat.

EDIT: I think this worked by unblocking some lower level permissions that enabled an outside program to access the outlook client.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Rory. Please explain the solution and why it worked for you in your answers instead of just posting links, as they tend to die sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Recalled Emails would have no Body hence we can find that via the MessageClass and exclude that particular Class

```
for i in messages:
    if email.MessageClass != "IPM.Outlook.Recall":
```